# Accessing and printing nested array

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following nested array.

```
Array
(
    [animals] => Array
        (
            [carnivores] => Array
                (
                    [tiger] => Array
                        (
                            [eyes] => 2
                            [legs] => 4                            
                        )

                    [lion] => Array
                        (
                            [eyes] => 2
                            [legs] => 4                            
                        )        
                )

            [herbivores] => Array
                (
                    [deer] => Array
                        (
                            [eyes] => 2
                            [legs] => 4                            
                        )

                    [elephant] => Array
                        (
                            [eyes] => 2
                            [legs] => 4
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I want to process the above array and build an insert query using foreach loop as follows:

```
INSERT INTO `abc` (column1,column2,column3,column4, column5)
        VALUES ('animals','carnivores','tiger','2','4');
.
.
.
.
INSERT INTO `abc` (column1,column2,column3,column4, column5)
        VALUES ('animals','herbivores','elephant','2','4');
```

How can I achieve this. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Write a function that goes through your array recursively and while iterating get all keys together into an array, which you then can implode and use it in the query.

Comment: yes you can do it, us a loop to take the value of inner array.

Comment: why have `[lion]` and `[deer]`  keys been missed from processing?

Comment: @AbhimanyuBind, Your answer is ready.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop every part of your array. Just use `foreach` 3 time. store the query in an array. Let your array is `$arr`.

**Your array:**

```
$arr = array(
    "animals" => array
        (
            "carnivores" => array
                (
                    "tiger" => array
                        (
                            "eyes" => '2',
                            "legs" => '4'
                        ),

                    "lion" => Array
                        (
                            "eyes" => '2',
                            "legs" => '4'
                        )        
                ),

            "herbivores" => array
                (
                    "deer" => array
                        (
                            "eyes" => '2',
                            "legs" => '4'
                        ),

                    "elephant" => array
                        (
                            "eyes" => '2',
                            "legs" => '4'
                        )
                )
        )
);
```

**Mechanism / Technique:**

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    $str = "INSERT INTO `abc` (column1,column2,column3,column4, column5) VALUES(";
    $qryArr = array();
    foreach($value as $key2 => $value2){
        foreach($value2 as $key3 => $value3){
            $eyes = $value3['eyes'];
            $legs = $value3['legs'];

            $qryArr[] = $str."'$key', '$key2', '$key3', '$eyes', '$legs');";
        }           
    }   
}

print_r($qryArr);
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => INSERT INTO `abc` (column1,column2,column3,column4, column5) VALUES('animals', 'carnivores', 'tiger', '2', '4');

    [1] => INSERT INTO `abc` (column1,column2,column3,column4, column5) VALUES('animals', 'carnivores', 'lion', '2', '4');

    [2] => INSERT INTO `abc` (column1,column2,column3,column4, column5) VALUES('animals', 'herbivores', 'deer', '2', '4');

    [3] => INSERT INTO `abc` (column1,column2,column3,column4, column5) VALUES('animals', 'herbivores', 'elephant', '2', '4');

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PDO for inserting and foreach to loop through all the values in multi array.

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `abc` (...) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$data = [];
foreach ($animals as $key_animals => $animalGroup) {
    foreach ($animalGroup as $key_animalGroup => $animal) {
        foreach ($animal as $key_animal => $animalProps) {
            $data = [$key_animals, $key_animalGroup, $key_animal, $animalProps['eyes'], $animalProps['legs']];
            $stmt->execute($data);
}}}
```

Have not tested this but something along these lines.